# ValueError: Solver lbfgs supports only 'l2' or 'none' penalties, got l1 penalty

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm running the process of feature selection on classification problem,  using the embedded method (L1 - Lasso) With LogisticRegression.

I'm running the following code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Lasso, LogisticRegression
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel

# using logistic regression with penalty l1.
selection = SelectFromModel(LogisticRegression(C=1, penalty='l1'))
selection.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

But I'm getting exception (on the `fit` command):

```
   selection.fit(x_train, y_train)
   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_selection\_from_model.py", line 222, in fit
   self.estimator_.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py", line 1488, in fit
   solver = _check_solver(self.solver, self.penalty, self.dual)
   File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py", line 445, in _check_solver
   "got %s penalty." % (solver, penalty))
   ValueError: Solver lbfgs supports only 'l2' or 'none' penalties, got l1 penalty.
```

I'm running under `python 3.7.6` and s`scikit-learn version is 0.22.2.post1`

What is wrong and how can I fix it ?

Comment: The ‘newton-cg’, ‘sag’, and ‘lbfgs’ solvers support only L2 regularization with primal formulation, or no regularization. The ‘liblinear’ solver supports both L1 and L2 regularization, with a dual formulation only for the L2 penalty. The Elastic-Net regularization is only supported by the ‘saga’ solver.
(see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is cleared up in the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html).

> **solver : *{‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘liblinear’, ‘sag’, ‘saga’}, default=’lbfgs’***
>
> ...
>
> - ‘newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘sag’ and ‘saga’ handle L2 or no penalty
> - ‘liblinear’ and ‘saga’ also handle L1 penalty

Call it like this:

```
LogisticRegression(C=1, penalty='l1', solver='liblinear')
```

Answer (score 2):

As l1 is supported by solver 'liblinear'. Always specify solver='liblinear' with penalty= 'l1'

selection = SelectFromModel(LogisticRegression(C=1, penalty='l1', solver='liblinear'))

Answer (score 2):

Just try to specify the solver that you want to use and then the error will be gone.
l1 support  'liblinear' and 'saga'
L2 handle  newton-cg’, ‘lbfgs’, ‘sag’ and ‘saga’

```
clf = LogisticRegression(C=0.01, penalty='l1',solver='liblinear');
```